# Passing a string from a form in html-file to a python-script respecting utf-8 encoding

Tags: php, python, html, encoding, utf-8

I have this form in a index.html file.

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input id="a" name="a" type="text">
    <input type="submit" name="run_query" value="Add User" size="30">
</form>
```

And I am trying to pass the text input to a pyton script as argument by embedding the following php code into the index.html file:

```
<?
    session_start();
    ob_start();
    if(isset($_REQUEST['run_query'])) {
    $add_user = $_REQUEST['a'];
    $command = "add_author.py $add_user";
        exec($command); 
    }
?>
```

I have put the add_author.py file into the same folder where index.html lays. It works fine with any string. But if I try to use strings which contains ä ö é it does not work.

The python file looks like this.

```
import sys
import codecs
if __name__ == '__main__':
    wFile = codecs.open("test.txt", "w", "utf8")
    wFile.write(" ".join(sys.argv[1:]))
    wFile.close()
```

By the way: The index.html has this line in it.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

I would love to hear from a better approach of managing my task or a correction of my approach. Thank you!

Comment: What is the operating system? What is the system encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Python directly with CGI. It should be faster than calling Python from PHP. It should be easier to configure too.

Simple example.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi;
import codecs;

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
my_a = form.getvalue("a","")

wFile = codecs.open("test.txt", "w", "utf8")
wFile.write(my_a);
wFile.close()

print("Content-Type: text/plain")
print("Location: ../plain.html")
print()
```

You have to put this python file into directory for CGI scripts. The most common is `/cgi-bin/`. Well, the server may need some configuration too.

The 3 last lines are simple http headers. In my example it just redirect to other site. There is no content to display. The `getvalue("a","")` will return value of field "a" or the empty string (second argument). Well, almost regular Python file.

Comment: I am new to webprogramming. Would you please give me an example how you would realize this example by CGI?

Comment: This one saved my day! Thank you very much or the example. I think I'll have a deeper look into cgi programming. It seems to solve more then the workarounds I tried so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not have PHP write to the file instead of calling another python script?

```
if (!$handle = fopen("test.txt", 'a')) {
    echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
    exit;
}

if (fwrite($handle, $_REQUEST['a']) === FALSE) {
    echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
    exit;
}
```

If you insist on using the python script maybe you need to encode it first, but generally check with the different approaches stated here:
http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html
My guess is that you just need to call unicode() on the string

```
wFile.write(unicode(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Comment: I need the pyton script. The "writing to a file is just a testcase" I want to do much more processing with python.

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

At the top of your file should force utf encoding.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

if __name__ in '__main__':
    with open('test.txt','w') as out:
        out.write(''.join(sys.argv[1:]).encode("utf-8"))
```

Should work just fine

Comment: Does the forcing of utf8 in python by the first line you posted mean, that every string will be present in utf8 and not like the standard in python (which is unicode)?

Comment: I tryed out your code, but it does not solve the problem. If I pas strings who are pure ascii it works. But with strings which contain non-ascii characters it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem with the PHP code seems to be that the argument "$add_user" added to the "command" is not escaped or secured in any way.
This makes it possible to send anything into the "exec", making the system vulnerable to attacks. The webcomic XKCD has a "funny" example of this problem: http://xkcd.com/327/

The cause of what you see is that UTF-8 encoded "åäö" begins with an unprintable byte that causes problems in many older shells, depending on system configuration.